# Auto matching the color of my brush to the color of a background layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a background layer which contains an image. I'm trying to auto map the color of my brush to take the color of the background. Is this possible? The following video illustrates it better, starting from minute 1:30.

[Oil paint effect in photshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqq8Rb6GInI)

Comment: Find a proper tutorial. Try searching youtube for "Photoshop art history brush tutorial". There's a good one here on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7SnfuIM778

Comment: Yeah, I'd point out that the tutorial you linked to is using the **History Brush** and not some standard brush.

Answer (score 0):

The feature "auto map the color of brush from background" is what "Art History Brush Tool" doing. You can select it by "Y" or "Shift+Y" key. And you will need a "History Brush". Standard brushes won't work, if you try to use them then the appropriate tool will be selected automatically and you can't use "Art History Brush".